# Crystal frequency for ATmega16A MCU

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, crystal

I am using a crystal of 16 MHz with an ATmega16A MCU.

As it is known that the crystals usually do not give us proper square wave and also the frequency is not that exact. So when I am enabling a 16 MHz clock for the ATmega16A in the setup, if the frequency is not that exact will that cause any problems?

Secondly, if I have a 20 MHz crystal and I change the capacitors to make it 16 MHz, will it work or do I have to use the exact 16 MHz?

Comment: What does the atmega16A datasheet state in regard to the crystal and oscillator?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT ;-) I'm fixing the uppercase in your title :)

Comment: The whole point of a crystal is that when used in an oscillator circuit, the frequency **is** very exact. So, "as it is known" seems to be partially wrong. You're right, a crystal doesn't give any signal, including a square wave, or any other wave. It needs to be part of an oscillator circuit. So, I think that sounds like a misunderstanding what a crystal actually is and what it isn't.

Comment: You can't pull a 20 MHz crystal down to 16 MHz. Down to 19.998 MHz almost certainly. If you get an oscillator with a 20 MHz crystal in it to somehow oscillate at 16 MHz, maybe you've turned it into a relaxation oscillator, it will be other components in the circuit controlling the oscillation frequency, not the crystal.

Comment: @Neil_UK So does that mean that using different value capacitors won't work creating oscillations but they would instead affect the resonance and maybe reduce the output voltage and frequency.

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaFarooq The caps at each end of the crystal produce the right impedance conditions for the feedback to be correct to maintain the oscillation. Small changes in their values, a few pF, change the oscillator frequency by ppm, parts per million, as the crystal has effective LC values of mH and fF, which totally swamp and control the external capacitor values - that's the whole point of using a crystal. Large changes in the values of the external capacitors destroy the correct feedback conditions, and the oscillator stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With crystals you do get quite precise freqency. Even a normal typical bog-standard cheapest crystals you can find is in the order of 100 PPM or better, which means 0.01% tolerance or better. 20 to 50 PPM is easily achievable with proper design and more expensive crystal. If you need much more precise clocks then you can't anyway use a crystal.

If the AVR is made to run with a 16 MHz crystal, it will work fine.

But you can't use a 20 MHz crystal. The AVR can't run at 20 MHz, and you can't change the 20 MHz crystal to run at 16 MHz, not by changing load caps or in any other way.

You have to use a crystal with suitable frequency. 16 MHz is only the maximum, you can use a crystal with smaller frequency.

Comment: well, nothing is stopping you from buying a 20MHz crystal and soldering it to the crystal pins, but the ATmega16A might not work properly.

Comment: @user253751 Of course, and same applies to all crystals above 16 MHz. The datasheet guarantees operation up to 16 MHz and is not intended to run above 16 MHz. Of course you can run it at any voltage or current or frequency combo out of guaranteed operation range and then complain when it does not work.